# Nomen als Adjektiv?

Tags: meaning, adjective

I have encountered this sentence:

> Warum schläft der Mensch ein Drittel seines Lebens? Damit Hirn und Seele entspannen? Oder **weil die Erde kahl wäre, gäbe der Allesfresser Mensch nicht zwischendurch Ruhe?**

The bold sentence is what confusing me. Please do me two favors:

1. Can you please translate it literally to English so that I would completely understand it?
2. Why is "Der Allesfresser Mensch" written like that as if "Allesfresser" is an adjective of "Mensch"?

Comment: There is no grammatical secret in this sentence. You should be able to translate it, if you have checked all words. It means that the humans eat all - like pigs, meat, vegetables, fruit, fish. Not like cows, which prefer gras only. Someone who eats all, can be named as Allesfresser, which a substantive and rather used for animals.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein A "hidden" (no conjunction) counterfactual conditional is something one would expect to be understood at the B2 level (i.e. it is an advanced topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The noun *Allesfresser* is a **Gattungsbezeichnung** or **Gattungsname** (*category designation, category name*). It is used like ...

- a profession,

  > Der ***Schuster** Weingruber* macht Schuhe. = The ***cobbler** Weingruber* makes shoes.
  > Der ***Dachdecker** Petrovich* deckt das Dach. = The ***roofer** Petrovich* covers the roof.
  > Der ***Bäcker** Steininger* bäckt Brot. = The ***baker** Steininger* bakes bread.
- a nationality,

  > Der ***Russe** Putin* spricht russisch. = *Putin, **the Russian,*** speaks Russian.
  > Der ***Österreicher** Kurz* ist jung. = The ***Austrian** Kurz* is young.
  > Der ***Franzose** Macron* lebt in Paris. = *Macron, **a Frenchman,*** lives in Paris.
- a denomination,

  > Der ***Katholik** Krautwaschl* ist Bischof. = *Krautwaschl, **a Catholic,*** is a bishop.
  > Der ***Jude** Hofmeister* ist Rabbiner. = The ***Jew** Hofmeister* is a rabbi.
  > Der ***Muslim** Koleib* ist Imam. = The ***Muslim** Koleib* is an Imam.
- an illness,

  > Der ***Diabetiker** Müller* muss Medikamente nehmen. = *Müller, **a diabetic,*** has to take medication.
  > Der ***Epileptiker** Hofmeister* liegt im Spital. = *Hofmeister, **an epileptic,*** is in the hospital.
  > Der ***Alkoholiker** Bauer* ist in Behandlung. = *Bauer, **an alcoholic,*** is in treatment.
- or a party affiliation.

  > Der ***Sozialdemokrat** Scholz* möchte Kanzler werden. = The ***Social Democrat** Scholz* wants to become chancellor.
  > Der ***Republikaner** Trump* wurde abgewählt. = ***Republican** Trump* was voted out of office.
  > Der ***Kommunist** Marx* schrieb ein Buch. = The ***communist** Marx* wrote a book.

This pattern is quite common in German, and as the examples show, it also exists in English, but is not as common in English as in German.

---

And here is the translation:

> Why do people sleep for a third of their lives? So that brain and soul can relax? Or because the earth would be bare, would *mankind, **the omnivore*** not rest in between?

Maybe also

> ... would the ***omnivore** man* not rest in between?

*<sup>Note, that this site is not a translation service. Translation requests are normally off topic, but in this case it makes sense to give you a correct translation.</sup>*

Comment: Note that the order can be switched around (*Weingruber, der Schuster*), which puts the proper noun first. It should be mentioned that this construction is known as [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition).

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

A translation would be

> Or because earth would be barren, if the omnivore humankind wouldn't rest once in a while.

"Allesfresser" is a normal noun here. I don't know the name of the construction, but basically it sets "Allesfresser" and "Mensch" equal. You can use the same contruction in English as I have done. It is similar to the phrase "der Maler Rembrandt": "the painter (called) Rembrandt".

Comment: In English you can switch it around: "Man the omnivore", "Rembrandt the painter".

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is something worth adding to the answer given by @RoToRa, particularly as you ask for a literal translation into English.

I think that a *close* rendition into *English* — rather than a word-by-word attempt — must (i) deal with the words *Allesfresser Mensch* that you specifically asked about, and (ii) correctly capture the Konjunktiv II form of the second part of the sentence (which you didn't mention and which isn't properly captured in the answer of @RoToRa )

As, so often with language, the choices that one has in translation are often constrained by context, but they are sometimes *expanded* by the context because it gives one an opportunity to rely on what the speaker already knows. The sentence fragment that you quote appears, slightly changed, in the Aspekte Neu B2 Lehrbuch where the context is as follows :

> Bis heute weiss die Wissenschaft nicht, warum der Mensch ein Drittel seines Lebens verschläft. Damit die Organe entspannen? Oder weil die Erde kahl wäre, gäbe der Allesfresser Mensch nicht zwischendurch Ruhe?

A close translation might be:

> To this day, science does not know why humans slept away a third of their lives. To allow the body to recuperate? Or because the earth would be bare *were* ***the omnivores*** not to give it occasional rest.

Clearly this differs from any kind of word-for-word approach to the German sentence but I do think that it gives a more "complete understanding" (at least to a native English speaker) of what is being said in the German. Specific points:

1. I think that Allesfresser Mensch is better rendered in the context simply as omnivores. It is obvious that we are talking about humans. So, although the German could be rendered as *ominvore humans* (compound-noun and ***not*** *humankind*), or more likely, *omnivorous humans* (adjective noun), the word *omnivores* seems better.
2. ... ***were** the omnivores not to* ... captures the [Konjunktive II](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geben) form of   *... gäbe ... nicht ...* .
3. ... ***slept away** a third ...* is a [better English rendition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/verschlafen) for *verschläft* than ***overslept***. (Of course, in the quotation as you have given it, with the verb *schlafen*, ***... slept a third ...*** would work just fine. The point about *slept away* is that it emphasizes the apparent waste.
4. One would be unlikely to read about resting "the organs" in an English translation; instead, unless there was specific evidence about how an organ such as the heart was affected by sleep, one would be more likely to read about "the body".

N.B. Thanks to Hubert Schölnast for highlighting an error in my terminology that detracted from the main point of my answer.

Comment: I guess, it should be _sleep away_, since it is Präsens in German.

Comment: Quote *»RotTaRa has already stressed that **Allesfresser Mensch** is a compound noun«* No. That's wrong! It is double wrong! Neither did RotTaRa or RoToRa (which is the correct name) say this, nor is it a compound noun. German compound nouns are always written as **one** word without any spaces between the components like *Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft* or *Fußbodenschleifmaschinenverleih.* If there is a space between the two parts, then we have two separate words which are **not** compound.

Comment: I have changed my answer to chop out the offending words, but it is worth pointing out that you are wrong! Although *Gattungsname* is a German word to describe the word *Allesfresser* in the noun-string *Allesfresser Mensch* there is no doubt that the English term *compound noun* **correctly** describes the double noun string *Allesfresser Mensch*, ... (continued)

Comment: ... in addition to correctly describing a word like *Fußbodenschleifmaschinenverleih*. Fowler's Modern English Usage and the OED explain that "compound" (noun, preposition, etc) describes a succession of like elements (nounal, propositional, etc.) that function together to produce a meaning different from that of any element on its own. ... (continued)

Comment: As for *Allesfresser Mensch*, is each of the elements a noun? Yes. Do the two words function together like a noun but with a meaning that is different from either of the two words alone? Yes ... Therefore, **compound noun** is a correct English description.

Comment: It is not a compound based on the fact alone that the first word is the one that changes: *des Allesfresser**s** Mensch*. The meaning is also different: *d**as** Problem Nachbar* is a problem, *d**er** Problemnachbar* a person.