Do insults require feminine forms?
In German when referring to someone's profession I had the impression it was mandatory to specify their gender, e.g. a female professor is "eine Professorin." However, is this required when using derogatory terms? Can a woman or girl be "ein Schlingel/ein Schuft" or do you need to say "eine Schlingelin/Schuftin?"
I realize these are not common terms in modern speech but I need to translate the terms "rogue" and "wretch."

I just want to point out that the premise when referring to someone's profession it is mandatory to specify their gender, e.g. a female professor is "eine Professorin" is wrong; sie ist Professor is possible (and some female professors will object to being referred to as Professorin, as others will object to Professor).

related question: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/62277/1487

It is not mandatory, because the masculine form serves as a catch-all. Sometimes it feels uncomfortable though. For instance, the topmost person in a state has the title "Landeshauptmann", and if this is a woman, this sounds a bit strange (due to the "mann" in the word), and nowadays we say "Landeshauptfrau" in this case. But for your case, "sie ist ein guter Arzt" is perfectly fine and neutral. Actually, the important piece of information is that this person is a competent doctor. As a patient you don't care whether it is a man or a woman.

You can check this on Wiktionary. Here is an example: The German noun Tänzer (dancer) is the name of a profession, i.e. a category name that has different male and female forms. If you look up Tänzer on Wiktionary you will find a section named Weibliche Wortformen with an entry for the female form:

Weibliche Wortformen:
[1] Tänzerin

This form links to the entry of Tänzerin, where you find these lines:

Männliche Wortformen:
[1] Tänzer

(The signs »[1]« just refers to the first meaning of the word. Tänzer and Tänzerin has only one meaning, so »[1]« is not really necessary here.)
However, if look up Schlingel, you will not find a section with the title Weibliche Wortformen. The absence of this section means, that there is only the male form.
But there is such a section in the Wiktionary entry for Schuft:

Weibliche Wortformen:
[1] Schuftin

And this means, that the form die Schuftin exists and can be used.
But be aware, that this form exists does not necessarily mean, that it is very common. You can check this with the Google ngram viewer.
Here is the frequency diagram for the two forms Tänzer and Tänzerin

source
You can see, that in the last two centuries both versions were used with about the same frequency. Compare this with the ngram for Schuft and Schuftin:

source
The male form "Schuft" has a maximum frequency of about 0.00016% at about the year 2020. But the line for "Schuftin" looks like a flat line, i.e. as if that word was not used at all. If you create the ngram for just "Schuftin" alone, you get this diagram:

source
You can see, that its maximum frequency is 0.00000009% in the year 2022. This means, that for about 1800 occurrences of »Schuft« there is only one occurrence of »Schuftin« in printed documents scanned by Google.

What does this mean?
This is absolutely correct:

Barbara ist eine gute Tänzerin.

The next version is grammatically not wrong, because German has a feature named generic masculinum, but it is considered to be male-chauvinistic, i.e. of bad style, therefor you better should not use it:

Barbara ist ein guter Tänzer.

If you want to use the word Schlingel, you must use the male form, because there is no feminine form:

Laura ist ein kleiner Schlingel.

There is nothing wrong about this.
If you want to use a form of Schuft, you have these two choices:


Sandra ist ein Schuft.
Sandra ist eine Schuftin.


If you write for a conservative audience, I would vote for version 1. If your audience is more progressive, then version 2 might be better. Another method to solve this problem is to avoid it by avoiding Schuft/Schuftin. Use Kanaille instead. This is a synonym for Schuft and it has the advantage, that it is a feminine noun.

Drück mal "Barbara ist der beste Tänzer in unserem Verein" mit Deiner sogenannt nicht-chauvinistischen, angeblich modernen Sprache aus.

@userunknown: »Barbara ist die beste Tänzerin in unserem Verein.« Ich gebe zu, dass diese Formulierung offen lässt, ob sie die Nummer 1 aller Vereinsmitglieder ist, oder ob sie nur die Nummer 1 der weiblichen Tänzerinnen ist. Aber exakt dasselbe Problem, nur mit umgekehrten Vorzeichen, tritt bei diesem Satz auf: »Rudolf ist der beste Tänzer in unserem Verein.« Ist Rudolf der beste von allen, oder nur der beste Mann? (Gibt eine Tänzerin in diesem Verein, die besser als Rudolf ist?)

All correct - but I'd add that politically correct choice of terminology is at best optional when deliberately being derogatory...

"If you want to use the word Schlingel, you must use the male form, because there is no feminine form:" - I think you leave out one important aspect, namely whether a given insult is applicable regardless of gender. I do not see this as a given - and I do wonder to what extent my intuition is simply wrong here. Still, I for one have a hard time imagining to apply the word "Idiot", for instance, to a female. "Sie ist ein Dummkopf." sounds right to me, but when I hear "Sie ist ein Idiot.", something feels off. I would instinctively change that e.g. to "Sie ist eine blöde Kuh."

@O.R.Mapper: One of my uncles often called my sister, when she was a child, a Schilgel. I see no problem in using such masculine nouns for female persons, like there is no problem using feminine nouns for male persons (»Walter ist eine Koryphäe in seinem Metier.«) or neuter nouns for any male or female person (»Jürgen ist ein Arschloch.« »Sabine ist ein Genie.«) About Idiot: This would be better: »Sie ist eine Idiotin.«

@HubertSchölnast: I do not have any issues with a mismatch between the person's sex and the grammatical gender of a noun. I rather perceive some nouns as inherently denoting a person of a particular sex, while others do not. Examples for nouns that I (possibly wrongly?) perceive as specific to male people: "Idiot", "Typ", "Vollhonk", "Schuft"; specific to female people: "Tussi", "blöde Kuh", "dumme Ziege"; applicable regardless of person's sex: "Koryphäe", "Genie", "Dummkopf", "Tratschtante". Maybe I'm totally off with this, but if anything, it seems to be a per-word difference that ...

... I cannot tie to any general rule. Indeed, "Idiotin" exists, but is IMHO not used a lot.

@HubertSchölnast: Nein, die männliche Form ist geschlechsübergreifend (siehe: Nichtschwimmerbecken) - sie kann nicht zugleich geschlechtsneutral und geschlechtsspezifisch sein, auch wenn das eine Minderheit seit 40 Jahren preigt.

@userunknown: Ob das, was du eine Minderheit nennst, tatsächlich eine Minderheit ist, müsste man erst mit wissenschaftlichen Methoden evaluieren. Meine Vermutung: Ältere Menschen (40+) sind eher deiner Meinung, jüngere werden dir eher widersprechen. Aber täglich sterben ältere Menschen und jüngere werden täglich neu geboren. Daher verschiebt sich dieses Verhältnis immer mehr zugunsten jener, die dir widersprechen.

@HubertSchölnast: a) Ich bezweifle, dass Du auch nur eine Person kennst, die mehr Menschen kennt, die aktiv die Gendersprache predigen als solche, die es nicht tun. b) Wenn Deine Überlegung zu Trends richtig wäre, dann hat bald jeder von uns zwei Skateboards, 3 MP-3-Player und einen Schnellkochtopf.

@userunknown: Ich kenne meine Studierenden und meine Kolleg:innen an meiner Hochschule (FH St. Pölten). Ich kenne auch die Sänger:innen in dem Chor, in dem ich singe (Wiener Singakademie) sowie viele Sänger:innen befreundeter Chöre. Das sind zusammen mehrere 100 Menschen. Ich gebe zu, dass der Akademiker:innenanteil in meinem Bekanntenkreis signifikant über dem Durchschnitt liegt, und dass daher dieses Sample nicht ...

... repräsentativ für die Gesamtbevölkerung ist. Aber um auf deinen Zweifel zu antworten: Wer von diesen Leuten aus meinem Bekanntenkreis inklusive Sprache aktiv predigt weiß ich nicht. Ich weiß aber, dass die meisten von ihnen inklusive Sprache aktiv verwenden, weil sie wertschätzender ist und zumindest versucht, niemanden auszugrenzen.

Sie mögen glauben, dass die Sprache wertschätzender sei, aber das macht die Sprache nicht wertschätzender und auch nicht weniger ausgrenzend, da die Mehrheit - womöglich nicht in Deiner Blase - die Sprache ablehnt. Die Sprache als "inklusiv" zu nennen ist ein Propagandistentrick, der glauben machen soll, die klassische Sprache sei weniger inklusiv. Du weisst also nicht, wer, oder ob überhaupt jmd. davon, die Gehirnwaschsprache predigt. Erst hattest Du noch großspurig verkündet, dass die Prediger keine Minderheit - also die Mehrheit sei. Jetzt kannst Du es plötzlich von k. einzig. Person sagen.

Dass die Sprache versucht, niemanden auszugrenzen, mag sein - der Versuch muss aber auf breiter Front scheitern, weil die Idee hinter dem Bemühen evidenzwidrig ist und zu Widersprüchen führt, die insbesondere Anfänger ausgrenzt. Nicht, weil diese sich missmutig und mutwillig nicht mitgemeint fühlen wollen, sondern weil sie die Sprache nicht verstehen und effektiv 2 Sprachen lernen müssen und wann man welche davon benutzen soll. Von Menschen mit einem IQ unter 100 gar nicht zu reden, also der weniger intelligenten Hälfte der Bevölkerung. Die werden faktisch, nicht bloß gefühlt, ausgegrenzt.

No, and don't do that.
Traditionally professions sometimes have an extra form for women, and seldomly an extra form for men e.g. die Krankenschwester → der Krankenpfleger. But that's almost exclusively for professions.
Two of the very few non-profession nouns with such a women counterpart are der Held — die Heldin and der Schurke — die Schurkin. Though you may see that as a profession, too, similar as der Prinz — die Prinzessin.
You can't use that pattern for arbitrary nouns.
For insulting women you have to use matching nouns. E.g. Du Schuft! — Du Hexe!
